# Get result of ShowCategoriesDialog in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In my code I open categorize dialog like this:

```
item.ShowCategoriesDialog();
```

Is it possible to determine whether user clicked "OK" or "Cancel" in the dialog?

Currently I compare item's categories before and after showing the dialog, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.